# Reset button using google events library

Tags: button, clojurescript

Hi I'm trying to create a reset button for this temperature widget. I want to click the button and have the input box be cleared. Right now, when I click, no matter what I do, the input in the text box doesn't go away.

Here is my code:

```
(ns learn-cljs.temp-converter
  (:require
   [goog.dom :as gdom]
   [goog.events :as gevents]))

(defn f->c [deg-f]
  (/ (- deg-f 32) 1.8))

(defn c->f [deg-c]
  (+ (* deg-c 1.8) 32))

(def celsius-radio (gdom/getElement "unit-c"))
(def fahrenheit-radio (gdom/getElement "unit-f"))
(def temp-input (gdom/getElement "temp"))
(def output-target (gdom/getElement "temp-out"))
(def output-unit-target (gdom/getElement "unit-out"))
(def reset-button (gdom/getElement "reset-button"))

(defn get-input-unit []
  (if (.-checked celsius-radio)
    :celsius
    :fahrenheit))

(defn get-input-temp []
  (js/parseInt (.-value temp-input)))

(defn set-output-temp [temp]
  (gdom/setTextContent output-target
                       (.toFixed temp 2)))

;; 5 event handling callback 
(defn update-output [_]
  (if (= :celsius (get-input-unit))
    (do (set-output-temp (c->f (get-input-temp)))
        (gdom/setTextContent output-unit-target "F"))
    (do (set-output-temp (f->c (get-input-temp)))
        (gdom/setTextContent output-unit-target "C"))))

(defn reset-temp [_]
    (gdom/setTextContent temp-input ""))

;; 6 attach event handlers 
(gevents/listen temp-input "keyup" update-output)
(gevents/listen celsius-radio "click" update-output)
(gevents/listen fahrenheit-radio "click" update-output)
(gevents/listen reset-button "click" reset-temp)
```

In my `index.html` file I have:

```
      <div>
        <input type="reset" id="reset-button">
      </div>
```

I can't for the life of me get this button to work? What do I do?

This is based on an exercise in the learn-clojurescript book, but I don't know where to find any answers for this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In my index.html I changed it to this:

```
        <form>
        <div class="temp-control">                             <!-- 2 -->
          <label for="temp">Temperature:</label>
          <input type="number" id="temp" name="temp" />
          <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </div>
      </form>
      </div>
```